# スタック・オーバーフローのMeetUp開催についてあなたの考えをお聞かせ下さい

Tags: 討議, 交流会

スタック・オーバーフローはプログラマーとプログラミングに熱心な人向けのオンラインコミュニティです。私たちは共に日本語のプログラミング知識を効率良く集積する為に日々協力しています。私たちはオンライン上ではお互いをよく知っているかもしれませんが、実際にはほとんどのユーザーに会ったことがありません。(◎_◎;)！

スタック・オーバーフローMeetUpを開催しませんか？

#### Stack Overflow コミュニティ MeetUp とは

[Stack Overflow MeetUp](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/17/stack-overflow-meetups-april-6/)の歴史は2011年に遡ります。「World-Wide Stack Overflow MeetUp Day」が開催され、翌年2012年には「[Second Annual](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/26/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/) Stack Overflow Meetup Day」が開催されました。ロシア語版コミュニティMeetUpは[毎年数回](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)開催されていますが毎回大成功です！[SOロシア語版コミュニティ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)や[SOスペイン語版コミュニティ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encuentros-locales)のMeetUpは頻繁に開催され、いつも楽しく有意義な時間を仲間と過ごしています！

#### MeetUpを主催するために何が必要ですか？

通常、コミュニティMeetUpはユーザー主導で行われ、Stack Exchange社は常にユーザーをサポートする形をとっています。コミュニティMeetUpを主催したい場合には次が必要です。

1. 仲間と楽しい夜を過ごしたいという思い。
2. メタにMeetUpについての投稿をする。（モデレータに「注目」タグをつけてもらうよう依頼してくださいね。）
3. MeetUpに参加できるユーザーからの返信を集めるための「フォーム」を作成する。（私は個人的に[Googleフォーム](https://www.google.com/intl/ja_jp/forms/about/)を使用しています。）フォームには以下のような質問を含めると良いでしょう：

   - 希望の開催日や開始時間
   - 希望の開催場所（都市やエリア）
   - 希望のMeetUpスタイル（プレゼンやライトニングトークをするのか、カフェやバーでカジュアルに交流するのか等）
   - その他コメントや提案の為のフィールド
   - スタック・オーバーフローアカウントへのリンクを追加する為のフィールド

ユーザーの連絡先を尋ねる主催者がいるかもしれませんが、これは必須ではありません。コミュニティのMeetUpは公のイベントであるため、それに関するすべての情報はメタで公開されるべきです。ユーザーに直接連絡する必要はありません。（それでも必要な場合は、チャットルームでユーザーに連絡できるでしょう。）

3. MeetUpの少なくとも1週間前に、正確なMeetUpの開催日、時間、場所、スタイルを確定します。それらの情報をメタでユーザーと共有します。
4. Stack Exchange社がMeetUp開催手配のお手伝いをしますので、サポートが必要だと思われた場合はどうぞ私にメールでご連絡ください。[ニコラス](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile)宛または[お問い合わせフォーム](/contact)から「Community Growth Team」に連絡してください。尚、MeetUpに参加するユーザーにステッカー等のSwagを配布する場合にはすぐに送付します。

コミュニティーのMeetUpは楽しい時間を共有するだけでなくお互いをより良く知るための絶好の機会です。

MeetUp開催についてあなたの考えをお聞かせ下さい。主催者側のユーザーに何か提案がありますか？あなたはMeetUpに参加できそうですか？それともあなたの街でMeetUpを主催してみますか？

フィードバックをいただければ幸いです。スタック・オーバーフローMeetUpを開催しましょう！

---

A lot of thanks to [@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) for the translation.

Answer (score 4):

この投稿を元に、2019年はとりあえずふたつの計画が投稿されました :)

- [参加者募集中：5/31(金)東京・渋谷でスタック・オーバーフローMeetUpが開催されます](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/19110)
- [東京以外の場所でMeetUpを開催したい方はいらっしゃいますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3000/19110)