# 希望者募集中：東京以外の場所でMeetUpを開催したい方はいらっしゃいますか？

Tags: 討議, 交流会

[2019年5月末に東京でMeetUpを開催しました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/19110)が、それ以外の場所で開催したい方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

東京は私 (@nekketsuuu) が取り仕切るのでひとまず開催できるのですが、名古屋や大阪など、他の都市についてはあまり多くのご意見を伺えなかったため現状予定が立っておりません。

日本の東京以外の都市でMeetUpを開催したい方、あるいは、開催されたら参加したい方がいらっしゃれば、是非回答やコメントで教えてくださいませ :)

Comment: 大阪、名古屋なら参加したいです。……ちょっと先の連休であれば何処だろうと参加出来ると思ってたり。

Comment: そもそもの参加したいと思っている人の分母が少ないのか反応が無いのが寂しいです。大阪、名古屋、東京以外でも「ここで実施して欲しい！」があれば是非聞きたいです。（例えば北海道とか九州圏とかですかね？）

Comment: @Sieg さんが開催したい都市で回答を投稿頂ければ、その都市で開催したい方がupvoteしてくれて大体の人数が把握できるかもしれないな、と思いました。

Comment: もちろん Sieg さん以外の方が「○○でやりたい！」という回答をご投稿いただいてもオールオッケーです！　要するに「やりたい人がいればやる」スタイルになります。

Comment: 一旦回答しました。回答した場所であれば私は参加できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 6):

開催場所：名古屋
予定候補地：名古屋駅周辺、栄

希望者の数を把握したいため、参加したい方がいらっしゃいましたらUpvoteをお願いいたします。
また、名古屋圏内で他に候補地があればコメント欄にて投稿ください。

Answer (score 0):

開催場所：大阪
予定候補地：難波、梅田

希望者の数を把握したいため、参加したい方がいらっしゃいましたらUpvoteをお願いいたします。
また、大阪圏内で他に候補地があればコメント欄にて投稿ください。